# Is this alternate definition of Limit correct?

Tags: limits, terminology, definition

Would it be correct to define the limit of a series as the smallest number that no number in the series is greater than (for an increasing series, the other way around for a decreasing series, i.e the greatest number that no number in the series is smaller than)?

EDIT: Based on Hagen's comment I realized I meant sequence, not series; I wasn't clear on the difference.

Comment: By "number in the series" do you mean, say, then $n$th term you are adding, or the $n$th partial sum?

Comment: IF you writte *sequence* instead of *series* and are satisfied with treating only monotonic sequences, then yes. $\lim a_n=\sup a_n$ for increasing (or non-decreasing)and $\lim a_n=\inf a_n$ for a decreasing (or non-increasing) sequence

Comment: @James, I mean the nth term. EDIT: I understand the confusion. From Hagen's post I just looked up the difference between series and sequence and I meant sequence, I'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but such a definition would not extend easily to sequences which are not monotone. Some examples are $(-1)^n$ which does not have a limit, but would have limit either 1 or -1 based on your definition, or $e^{-n}\sin(n)$, which has a limit of 0 but has no such limit based on either of your definitions.